# Equation of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given the sequence below, find an equation for $n$ where $n$ = the number of the term.

$${ 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0}$$

$n_1 = 1$ 
$n_2 = 0 $
$n_3 = -1$
$n_4 = 0$

This repeats with every four numbers and I understand how to write equations for sequences generally, but I have no idea how to write the equation for this $1$ in terms of $n$. What would the equation be?

Answer (score 3):

What about $\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)$?

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility of writing a function in two parts

$t_n = 0 $  if $n$ is even
$t_n = (-1)^{\frac {n-1}2}$ if $n$ is odd

You can also write using the $mod$ function as

$t_n = (-1)^{\frac {n-1}2} \times n$ $mod$ $2$

$mod$ is nothing but the remainder function. If $n$ is even, remainder is $0$, else remainder is $1$

Comment points out that there are other functions as well, such as

$\sin(\frac{\pi n}2)$
$\cos(\frac{\pi n}2-\frac{\pi}2)$
etc..

Note- $t_n$ refers to the $n^{th}$ term of the series

Comment: True. I haven't thought of that. Sin , Cos etc.. do work. In fact there are infinite functions that can be formed for the series.

Answer (score 0):

And there's also $\Re i^{n-1}$.